# Is that possible to allow cyclic reference in pom

Tags: java, maven

I have two child maven modules.

is that possible to have a cyclic reference in the two modules? What I mean is I have a class in module A that is needed in module B and viceversa.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  POM dependencies cannot be cyclic.

If you have mutually dependent classes:

- put them the same Maven module, or
- refactor them so that the dependencies are on interfaces, and then push the interfaces into a common Maven module that modules A and/or B can depend on.

As a rule of thumb, classes with cyclic dependencies ought to be in the same package, and a Maven module should consist of one or more distinct packages.  Class dependency cycles that span multiple packages are generally thought to be undesirable ... and indicative of flawed modularization.

Comment: what suggestion do you have then. I have to recreate the Class in both Modules or I have to create a third module that contains both classes

Comment: I would suggest to create a third module containing the classes you need in both modules. Never duplicate your code on purpose.

Comment: good, accept your answer. Then I have to find **better naming** that will reflect the nature shared classes